# Extracting Nightlights data using R

Tags: raster, r, sp

I am working with Bangladesh data and want to create an annual Nightlights index for all sub-districts. I am using R package named "nightlights". I used this following code, and get a CSV file that has columns with NightLight name, but these columns do not have any data (NULL). I am wondering what went wrong.

This is my current code.

```
    ##Extract Nightlights information for Bangladesh Upazila##

##Download Package##

if (!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("walshc/nightlights")

install.packages(nightlights)
library(nightlights)
require(nightlights)

#Bangladesh admin level 3 data##
shp <- rgdal::readOGR("BGD_adm", "BGD_adm3")

# Download and extract some night lights data to a directory "night-lights":
downloadNightLights(years = 1999:2000, directory = "night-lights")

# By default, the function gets the sum of night lights within the regions:
nl.sums <- extractNightLights(directory = "night-lights", shp)
```

##I get a CSV file with nl.sums and there are all variables but the nightlights data columns are NULL (no data)

```
# Specificy other statistics to get, e.g. the mean & standard deviation:
nl.mean.sd <- extractNightLights(directory = "night-lights", shp,
                                 stats = c("mean", "sd"))
```

What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: trying to look at this but the nightlight data download keeps failing at about 1/20 the way. Meanwhile, can you show us something about your `shp` object, or the shapefile its coming from? `summary(shp)` perhaps? That's the only other thing stopping this from being reproducible (that and the breaking download...)

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for looking into this! This is what I get from summary(shp):

summary(shp)
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
       min      max
x 88.01057 92.67366
y 20.74111 26.63440
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string : [+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs]
Data attributes:
     ID_0               ISO               NAME_0         
 Length:463         Length:463         Length:463        
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character

Comment: Has it successfully downloaded the data into your "night-lights" directory (folder)? You should have some large .tif files. named something like `F162006.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif` - also when you do the `extractNightLights` it should print out "Extracting night light data for year..." as it goes. You should see the tif files with `list.files("night-lights", "tif$")`